# Use a variable to refer to other variables?

Tags: excel, vba

So my macro uses many string constants to store the filenames of workbooks I want to edit. Each variable uses the naming convention `template` and then a 3 digit number (e.g. `template001`). Is there a way I can use an integer variable to refer to which constant I want to use? I'm imagining something like this:

```
Public Const filepath = "C:\Templates\"
Public Const template001 = "001.xls"

Sub printTemplate()

Dim num As Integer: num = 001
Dim template As Workbook

Set template = Workbooks.Open(filepath & GetVar("template" & num)) 'Complete guess at what the function is called
template.PrintOut
template.Close False

End Sub
```

Is there any such function that does this?

Comment: Have a read about [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays).

Comment: Yeah I realize I could just load all the constants into an array and refer to them by their index. But the 3 digit numbers are based on serial numbers and aren't sequential. It would be a lot easier to keep straight in my head if I could do it the way I show above.

Comment: I still do net get it completely...

Comment: @Falco Alexander  the part I'm asking about is `GetVar("template" & num)`. Is there a way I can refer to a constant/variable by constructing a string of its name?

Comment: You don't need the `GetVar` at all. Use `Workbooks.Open(filepath & Format(num, "000") & ".xls")` to build your filename

Comment: @PeterT the actual filenames are a lot more complicated than what I put in the example, so that wouldn't work for me

Comment: Have you considered looping through the files and only accessing those whose names match the desired pattern? Something like `InStr(myFileName, "template") > 0` may be enough

Comment: Use a dictionary.